# Access Stack Exchange using Pale Moon browser

Tags: discussion, browsers

I'm giving the browser [Pale Moon](http://www.palemoon.org/) a try, it's been fine so far apart from that I can't login to Stack Exchange on it. I've tried to login in multiple times, and on every attempt the banner at the top appears saying "welcome back [user]..." but then I am redirected back to the page which I tried to login from. To illustrate:

[image]

I really like the browser, but I can't use it if I can't access this website! So I'm hoping that it's not a bug and rather than I've not installed a certain plug-in or something.

Comment: This seems like a problem with the browser rather than SE. I suggest migrating back.